# If-Modified-Since request in iOS

Tags: ios, get, synchronization

I try to synchronise local data with server. Is it possible to use get "if-Modified-Since" request in IOS?

```
If-Modified-Since = "If-Modified-Since" ":" HTTP-date
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set HTTP fields with an `NSMutableURLRequest`:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"Your string" forHTTPHeaderField:@"If-Modified-Since"];
// ...
```

You can then check the status code of the response and look specifically for `304` (Not Modified).

Comment: The best way is to save the value of the `Last-Modified` field from the previous request. You then avoid date format strings and conversions and whatever other server-specific details or quirks exist.